# how to estimate the least square parameters in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, linear-regression, dolphindb

X is the matrix of independent variables and y is the dependent variable. X and y are stored in multiple data sources. how to estimate the least square parameters of X and Y? 
I write sql code as bellow，

```
def myOLSMap(table, yColName, xColNames){
   x = matrix(table[xColNames])
   xt = x.transpose();
   return xt.dot(x), xt.dot(table[yColName])
}
def myOLSEx(ds, yColName, xColNames){
   return mr(ds, myOLSMap{, yColName, xColNames}, +)
}
```

but I don't know how to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to obtain the statistics for the estimated model. DolphinDB's built-in linear regression function `ols` and `olsEx` (distributed version) shows not only the estimated parameters, but also the model statistics.